# Potentiometer heats up after changing wiring

Tags: led, wiring, potentiometer

I changed wiring on my LED array. I switched from a [24 AWG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0791C68HJ) to [18 Gauge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003J6368U) cable. I used the following [potentiometers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L74P6B3). However after changing wiring, all potentiometers (tried new ones and unused) started heating up really fast and slowly turning off probably from overheating protection. A significant change was that I increased the length of the wiring by 6 feet.

Any idea on what could cause that? If I plug the LEDs directly into the power supply they work fine for prolonged times.

Comment: Sounds like you have shorted something.

Comment: Could you provide a circuit diagram of what you are doing? Thanks.

Comment: The LEDs are connected in series, directly to a power supply.

Comment: Is the power supply going unstable with the long wires?  Assuming there isn't a short...

Comment: Those are **not** potentiometers.  They are pulse width modulation controllers that have potentiometers as part of the control.

Comment: @Aaron the power supply is stable (as in I have had it plugged in for 16 hours without issues)

Comment: have you measured it?

Answer (score 0):

The change in wire gauge means more current can flow.  I expect you're getting too much current through the pulse width modulator controllers you linked to.

24AWG wire has a higher resistance per foot than 18AWG wire.  I expect the higher resistance of the 24AWG was keeping the current below the rated current of the controller.  You switched to thicker wire with less resistance, so there's more current going through the LEDs and the controller.  That additional current is making the switching transistor in the controller get hot.

Comment: what can I do to mitigate that?

Answer (score 0):

They ought to heat up because you used 18g wire which is way thicker than the recommended 24g wire. There was excessive current drawn due to the very low resistance of the replacement wire. Squaring that current (I2R) explains the excessive rise in heat.

Comment: where did you find the recommended wire?

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the 24awg wire that's the before. Simple.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please add some reasoning and explanation to your answer. Without that it is likely to be deleted. Thank you.